# How to fix State that is persisting on pagination?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello beautiful people!

I'm building a MERN stack website and having a problem with this Edit Mode state:

[image]

- When I click on the **Edit button**, it will set the **Edit mode** to `true` and display the input field.
- I click on the **Edit button** again to set the **Edit mode** to `false` and hide the input field.
- But if I don't change the **Edit mode**'s state to `false` and go to the next page - The input field will display on the same row number on the next page but cleared out the previous input.
- The Update (Checkmark) button and other buttons in the rows work fine

-> How to reset the state and/or make the **Edit button** automatically hide when we move to other page?

### Here's my code:

**- Pagination:**

```
export default function Pagination({ foodPerPage, totalFood, paginate, currentPage }) {
    const pageNumbers = []

    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalFood / foodPerPage); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i)
    }
    return (
    <nav aria-label="Pagination" className="pagination">
        <ul>
            {pageNumbers.map(number => (
                <li key={number} className="page-item">
                    <button 
                        className={(currentPage === number ? "page-link active" : "page-link")}
                        onClick={() => paginate(number)}
                    >
                        {number}
                    </button>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

**- App.js**

```
export default function DinnerIdeas() {
    const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([])

    const [searchedFood, setSearchedFood] = useState([])
    const [noResult, setNoResult] = useState(false)

    
    
    // Display food list:
    useEffect(() => {
      let unmounted = false
      Axios.get("https://my-project.herokuapp.com/read")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setFoodList(response.data)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`The error is: ${error}`)
        return
      })
      return () => {
        unmounted = true
      }
    }, [foodList])
    


      // Paginate states:
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
      const [foodPerPage] = useState(5)
      
      // Get current food:
      const indexOfLastFood = currentPage * foodPerPage
      const indexOfFirstFood = indexOfLastFood - foodPerPage
      const currentFood = foodList.slice(indexOfFirstFood, indexOfLastFood)
      const currentSearchedFood = searchedFood.slice(indexOfFirstFood, indexOfLastFood)
      
      const paginate = (pageNumber) => {
        setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
      }
    
    return (
      <section>
        {noResult ? <ResultNotFound/>
          :
            <FoodListTable
              foodList={foodList}
              currentFood={currentFood}
              searchedFood={searchedFood}
              currentSearchedFood={currentSearchedFood}
              totalFood={foodList.length}
              totalSearchedFood={searchedFood.length}
              currentPage={currentPage}
              paginate={paginate}
              noResult={noResult}
              foodPerPage={foodPerPage}
            />
        }
      </section>
    )
  }
```

**- FoodListTable.js**

```
import FoodListRow from './FoodListRow'
import Pagination from "../Pagination"


export default function FoodListTable(props) {
    return (
        <div className="flist container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Food name
                        </th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>
                            Action
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.searchedFood.length > 0 ? props.currentSearchedFood.map((val, key) => {
                        return (
                            <FoodListRow
                                val={val}
                                key={key} 
                                foodName={val.foodName}
                                isVegetarian={val.isVegetarian}
                                priceRange={val.priceRange}
                                foodUrl={val.foodUrl}
                            />    
                        )
                    }) : props.currentFood.map((val, key) => {
                        return (
                            <FoodListRow
                                val={val}
                                key={key}
                                foodName={val.foodName}
                                isVegetarian={val.isVegetarian}
                                priceRange={val.priceRange}
                                foodUrl={val.foodUrl}
                            />
                        )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {props.searchedFood.length > 0 ? 
                <Pagination foodPerPage={props.foodPerPage} totalFood={props.totalSearchedFood} paginate={props.paginate} currentPage={props.currentPage} />
                :<Pagination foodPerPage={props.foodPerPage} totalFood={props.totalFood} paginate={props.paginate} currentPage={props.currentPage} />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**- FoodListRow Component inside `<FoodListTable/>`**

```
export default function FoodListRow(props) {
    // Edit mode:
    const [editBtn, setEditBtn] = useState(false)

    const handleEdit = () => {
        setEditBtn(!editBtn)
    }

    return (
        <tr key={props.val._id}>
            <td>
                {props.val.foodName}
                // Display the input field on Edit mode:
                {editBtn && 
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="edit"
                            placeholder="New food name.."
                            autoComplete="off"
                            onChange={(event) => {setNewFoodName(event.target.value)}}
                        />
                        <button
                        onClick={() => updateFoodName(props.val._id)}
                        >
                            ✓
                        </button> 
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
            <td>{props.val.priceRange}</td>
            <td>
                <a 
                    href={props.val.foodUrl} 
                    className="flist__table--btn"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer" 
                >
                    
                </a>
                <button 
                    onClick={handleEdit}
                >
                    ✏️
                </button>
                <button 
                    onClick={() => deleteFood(props.val._id)}
                >
                    ❌
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error must be on the code you've not share: `FoodListTable`
You probably map to render your `FoodListRow` using the map index as a `key`.

SO when you change your page from Pagintion, the `key` stays the same across render and your inner state is not changed.

So either use something else as key for `FoodListRow` (for exemple a database ID) or include your current page pagination in your key

Comment: Thank you, I have added the `FoodListTable` in my question. I did map out a `val` & `key` and passed them into `FoodListRow`. But inside `FoodListRow`, I use the `_id` (database ID) as the key so. Is this the same as what you mean?

Comment: You're using the map index as a key from `FoodListTable` when redering your `FoodListRow`. So yes it's the behavior I've described. Change it to `key={val._id}` and you should not have anymore problem

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! :) My last question is do I need to map out the `key`( map index ) from `FoodListTable` anymore if I'm not using it?

Comment: If you're not using it, no need to write it :)
`props.currentFood.map(val => {...})` is enough!